# GO: Permission denied when creating a cgroup with NewManager call

Tags: linux, go, cgroups

**UPDATE:**
*I can't reproduce the problem anymore. The below code works fine in both cases. (I am not sure if I should remove the question then.)*

---

I use cgropus GO package v2, and I can't create a cgroup with some parameters set to non-default values. I run CentOS-9.

The following GO code works fine:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    cgroupsv2 "github.com/containerd/cgroups/v2"
)
func main() {
    res := cgroupsv2.Resources{}
    //quota := int64(200000)
    //period  := uint64(1000000)
    //max := cgroupsv2.NewCPUMax(&quota, &period)
    //cpu := cgroupsv2.CPU{Max: max}
    //res = cgroupsv2.Resources{CPU: &cpu}
    cgroupManager, err := cgroupsv2.NewManager("/sys/fs/cgroup/", "/mytestgroup", &res)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating cgroup: %v\n", err)
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Println("The group created successfully")
    }
    cgroupManager.Delete()
}
```

---

```
$ go build -o test
$ sudo ./test
The group created successfully
```

However, if I uncomment commented-out lines, I get a permission error.

```
$ go build -o test
$ sudo ./test
Error creating cgroup: open /sys/fs/cgroup/mytestgroup/cpu.max: permission denied
```

Here is SELinux status, in case that matters

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33
```

**Thank you for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this code and it runs just fine

```
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        cgroupsv2 "github.com/containerd/cgroups/v3/cgroup2" // Old lib is not resolved
)
func main() {
        res := cgroupsv2.Resources{}
        quota := int64(200000)
        period  := uint64(1000000)
        max := cgroupsv2.NewCPUMax(&quota, &period)
        cpu := cgroupsv2.CPU{Max: max}
        res = cgroupsv2.Resources{CPU: &cpu}
        cgroupManager, err := cgroupsv2.NewManager("/sys/fs/cgroup/", "/mytestgroup", &res)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error creating cgroup: %v\n", err)
                return
        } else {
                fmt.Println("The group created successfully")
        }
        cgroupManager.Delete()
}
```

In the event that the code does not execute as expected, kindly verify if the `/sys/fs/cgroup` directory has the necessary read-write (`rw`) permissions. You can check the current mount options for the `/sys/fs/cgroup` filesystem by executing the following command:

```
mount | grep /sys/fs/cgroup
```

If the `/sys/fs/cgroup` filesystem is mounted as read-only, you can remount it with read-write permissions using the following command:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /sys/fs/cgroup
```

then try running your program again.

Comment: Thank you. I can also run this code today with no errors, which is very strange. Yesterday, it didn't run on both local VM box and in GCP. The bad thing is that I can't see what has changed.¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @dmitri One obvious difference is your code imports `cgroupsv2 "github.com/containerd/cgroups/v2"` while this answer imports `cgroupsv2 "github.com/containerd/cgroups/v3/cgroup2"`. Perhaps there was a bug in the older cgroups package.

Comment: @KurtisRader, sorry, I should have said that I tested the same import today as I did yesterday—"github.com/containerd/cgroups/v2"

Comment: @KurtisRader, I might have created a mess with imports (I am new to go). If I start a fresh module with only `cgroupsv2 "github.com/containerd/cgroups/v2"` import, it doesn't compile with errors like `cgroupsv2.NewCPUMax undefined`. I added `require github.com/containerd/cgroups v1.1.0` to `go.mod` file, which fixed the issue. I guess that is the wrong approach. I need to figure out the right way.